# how to make my plugin backward compatible to other versions of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I created a eclipse plugin in eclipse indigo but when i try to install it in helios i get the below error.

```
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.7.3' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency
```

How to make my plugin compatible with all versions of eclipse? Also is it mandatory to give  Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment?

Greg, my manifest file is below

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Codeanalysis
Bundle-SymbolicName: codeanalysis; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: codeanalysis.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.7.3",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101",
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.7.2"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `MANIFEST.MF` for the plugin

Comment: You can't.  You have to code your Eclipse plug-in in the lowest Eclipse that you plan to support.  Eclipse plug-ins are sometimes forward compatible.  Eclipse plug-ins are never backward compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment) has nothing to do with the version of Eclipse or a plug-in's version.

Look more closely at the manifest contents and the error message you received. I would add that changing the numbers doesn't automatically make it compatible--you should test against Helios to be sure as well.

Comment: Sorry. . My doubt about Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment should have been in a separate thread.