# How to target both Juno and Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse-juno, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-pde

I've written an Eclipse plugin using Kepler.  Now that it's code complete I attempted to install it using Juno to test backwards compatibility and came up with this error on installation:

```
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Expression Language 3.4.300.v20110228 (org.eclipse.core.expressions 
3.4.300.v20110228) 
Expression Language 3.4.401.v20120912-155018 
(org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.401.v20120912-155018) 
Expression Language 3.4.401.v20120627-124442 
(org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.401.v20120627-124442) 
Expression Language 3.4.400.v20120523-2004 
(org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.400.v20120523-2004) 
Expression Language 3.4.501.v20131118-1915 
(org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.501.v20131118-1915)
```

As seen above, Kepler wants Expression 3.4.500 while Juno uses 3.4.401.  I've tried removing the minimum version requirement from the org.eclipse.core.expressions plug in (it had been previously set to 3.4.500), but to no avail.

What is the correct method to write a plugin that supports both Juno and Kepler?  At the very least what is required to resolve this dependency issue?

As requested, here's the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: My Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.eclipse;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.2.2
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.eclipse.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: MyCompany Inc
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.1",
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.8.2",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.8.2",
 org.eclipse.ui.editors;bundle-version="3.8.0",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.8.3",
 com.mycompany.eclipse.dependencies;bundle-version="0.1.3",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.500"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7,
 JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
sherpaManifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 resources/,
 icons/,
 static/
```

According to a [comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654602/how-to-make-my-plugin-backward-compatible-to-other-versions-of-eclipse?rq=1) plugins are never backwards compatible.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF for your plugin.

Comment: @greg-449, added at your request.

Answer (score 2):

The `bundle-version` value for the plugin in the `Require-Bundle` entry in the plugin `MANIFEST.MF` determines the version of the dependency that is required.

You have:

```
org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.500"
```

which is saying that your plugin requires at least version 3.4.500 of the expressions plugin. Change the version to 3.4.401 to work with Juno.

Comment: If we remove `bundle-version="3.4.500"`. Platform refers to the latest version(If multiple version found) or whichever available. Is it correct?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Yes it will use whatever is available.

Comment: @greg-449, I tried this and got the same result, it's still requiring  3.4.500.

Comment: Is it just your plugin you are installing or are other plugins packaged with it (such as the expressions plugin)?

Comment: This is just my plugin, but I have noticed that the expressions 3.4.500 jar file is included in the site when I build it.